# How do I get rid of this VBA compiler error? Can't assign to read_only property

Tags: vba, excel

So I am completely new to this whole programming thing especially when it comes to VBA. I am trying to make this excel sheet for work that takes a parts list with an in stock inventory and a need on hand inventory column and sends me (and other coworkers) an email of what needs ordered when the in stock inventory is less than or equal to the need on hand inventory. The following is what I have so far (this is by going off of other work I have researched): Oh so what is happening is I had it kind of working but I am getting the error in the message box and cannot figure out how to fix it.Thanks in advance for the help.

Code:

```
Sub SendEmailOnPart()

'Move rows to new sheet for either TRUE or FALSE (needs ordered or does not)
  Dim firstrow, lastrow, r, torow As Integer
  Dim fromsheet, tosheet As Worksheet
  firstrow = 1
  Set fromsheet = ActiveSheet
  lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
  For r = firstrow To lastrow
    If fromsheet.Cells(r, "H") <> "" Then  'skip rows where column H is empty
      On Error GoTo make_new_sheet
      Set tosheet = Worksheets("" & fromsheet.Cells(r, "H"))
      On Error GoTo 0
      GoTo copy_row
make_new_sheet:
      Set tosheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
      tosheet.Name = fromsheet.Cells(r, "H")
copy_row:
      torow = tosheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
      fromsheet.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Copy
      tosheet.Cells(torow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
  Next r
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  fromsheet.Activate

' Go to the false worksheet

 Sheet ["FALSE"].Select

 ' Send Email of parts that need ordered

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItemItem)

    olMail.To = "Josh.Emory@techii.com"
    olMail.Subject = "Part Room"
    olMail.Body = ""
    olMail.Send

' Delete sheet after sending email

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheet ["TRUE"].Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

:Code

Comment: Which line is raising the error?  Also, do **not** use GoTo statements like that :)  Also, your variables aren't typed correctly.  Let me know which line causes the error I'll help you fix the other issues, too.

Comment: `Sheet["FALSE"].Select`  I'm pretty sure this is going to be an error, what are you trying to do with this statement?

Comment: maybe `Sheets("FALSE").Select`.

Comment: @Jeeped code won't even compile the way it is, so that line isn't causing the error

Comment: I also note that you're sending a blank email. What are you trying to send?

Comment: @DavidZemens I am comparing the inventory in stock and the Inventory on hand. This is giving me a true and false statement in column H to let me know if that part needs ordered or not. So with the Sheet["FALSE"].Select statement I am trying to go to the sheet with only the FALSE word in column H. This sheet is what i am trying to create with the code. In the blank email i am trying to then send myself an email that has this sheet i have created with the FALSE code in it.

Comment: Ok I kind of understand. I don't think you need either of those statements in the code at all. Take some time testing out my answer below and if you have any questions or errors just LMK.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah i already took them out. I put your code in and after looking at it i realized that i did not need it. I am sure i will need some more help but i am going to see what I can come up with on my own following your advice so that I can learn instead of taking the easy way out and just keep asking questions until you basically do it all for me. lol Thanks again for the help, I hope one day to pass be able to pass on help to others.

Comment: @DavidZemes Okay well I guess i already have one. So instead of deleting the sheet that the TRUE and FALSE are going onto i am just deleting the content using this code Sub Clear()

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
Sheet3.Cells.ClearContents

End Sub when i run the code you helped with though it is showing up after the content that was previously there. for example it is showing up on line 243 instead of number 1?

Answer (score 4):

`olMailItemItem` isn't valid.  Using `Option Explicit` will help you avoid typos like this.

These lines are going to cause an error:

```
Sheet ["FALSE"].Select    
Sheet ["TRUE"].Select
```

Use Long data type instead of integer, Worksheet rows exceed the limit for Integer type.

Each variable needs a type assignment, `Dim i, j, k as Long` is actually equivlant to `Dim i as Variant, j as Variant, k as Long`.  This can have unintended side-effects.

From style perspective, declaring multiple variables inline makes code less legible, and I would also recommend against it.

Declare each var on its own line, and declare ALL variables. Using `Option Explicit` helps enforce the latter.

There's no need to "Activate" a sheet if you're using proper object variables (you are). You only work with two worksheets: `fromsheet` and `tosheet`. Instead of activating a sheet, and then deleting the activesheet, just delete the worksheet directly (e.g., `fromsheet.delete` etc.)

**This should at least get you started**, but as you can see from the wall of text above, it was full of errors and doubtless I missed some of them.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendEmailOnPart()
'1. Declare all variables on their own line
'2. Use Long data type instead of integer for your counter variables
'3. Put all of your declarations at the top of module, also for readability
'4. Declare ALL variables and use Option Explicit
'5. Get rid of "GoTo" spaghetti code & replace with more proper local Error handler
  Dim firstrow As Long
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim r as Long
  Dim torow As Long  
  Dim fromsheet As Worksheet
  Dim tosheet As Worksheet
  Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application 
  Dim olMail as Object 'Outlook.MailItem
  Const olMailItem as Long = 0 'In case of late-binding

  firstrow = 1
  Set fromsheet = ActiveSheet

  'You've assigned ActiveSheet to variable fromsheet, so use it correctly:
  lastrow = fromsheet.Cells(fromsheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
  For r = firstrow To lastrow
    If fromsheet.Cells(r, "H") <> "" Then  'skip rows where column H is empty
      On Error Resume Next  '## Not ideal, but this is an OK place to use On Error Resume Next
      Set tosheet = Worksheets("" & fromsheet.Cells(r, "H"))
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      '# If there was an error, then create the new sheet
          Set tosheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
          tosheet.Name = fromsheet.Cells(r, "H")
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

      torow = tosheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

      fromsheet.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Copy
      tosheet.Cells(torow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
  Next r
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Go to the false worksheet
 Sheet["FALSE"].Select  '<~~ This line is going to cause an error  ####

 ' Send Email of parts that need ordered
 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = "Josh.Emory@techii.com"
    olMail.Subject = "Part Room"
    olMail.Body = ""
    olMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: okay thank you for the help i am going to have to take some time to go over all of this information that you posted to digest it all and move forward. Again thank you for the help